# case + how to implement equal or less or greater in case syntax

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, arithmetic

My target is to verify a range of number with (only with `case` + `esac`), and print the range. So for example:

- If the number is between 0 and 80, print `>=0<=80`
- If the number is between 81 and 100 then print `>=81<=100`
- etc.

The problem with my script below print only `>=0<=90` only if the number between 0 and 9.
How to fix my script, so that it will print correct output according to the number range?

```
#!/bin/ksh
read number 
case $number in 
 [0-80])  echo ">=0<=80";; 
 [81-100]) echo ">=81<=100";; 
 [101-120]) echo ">=101<=120";;
 [121-300]) echo ">=121<=300";;
esac
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`case` is only for pattern matching, it won't do arithmetic evaluation (except maybe if you consider `zsh`'s `<x-y>` extended pattern matching operator). The `[...]` is only to match **one** character (or *collating element* in some implementations) based on the set specified within. So for instance `[0-80]` would match **one** character if it's one of `0` to `8` or `0` (that is, one of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).

You could match numbers with patterns like:

```
case $(($number)) in
  ([0-9]|[1-7][0-9]|80) echo ">=0<=80";;
  (8[1-9]|9[0-9]|100) echo ">=81<=100";;
  ... and so on
esac
```

But you can easily see that it's not the right tool.

The `[...]` matches *one* character against the list of specified characters, so `[121-300]` matches for any character that is either 1, 2, 1 to 3, 0 or 0, so it's the same as `[0-3]` or `[0123]`.

Use:

```
if [ "$number" -ge 0 ] && [ "$number" -le 80 ]; then
  echo ">=0<=80"
elif [ "$number" -ge 81 ] &&  [ "$number" -le 100 ]; then
  echo ">=81<=100"
elif ... and so on
  ...
fi
```

Another way to use `case` would be like:

```
case $((
  (number >= 0 && number <= 80)   * 1 +
  (number > 80 && number <= 100)  * 2 +
  (number > 100 && number <= 120) * 3 +
  (number > 120 && number <= 300) * 4)) in
  (1) echo ">=0<=80";;
  (2) echo ">=81<=100";;
  (3) echo ">=101<=120";;
  (4) echo ">=121<=300";;
  (0) echo "None of the above";;
esac
```

Or use the ternary operator  (`x ? y : z`):

```
case $((
  number >= 0 && number <= 80   ? 1 :
  number > 80 && number <= 100  ? 2 :
  number > 100 && number <= 120 ? 3 :
  number > 120 && number <= 300 ? 4 : 0)) in...
```

Or like @mikeserv, think outside the box, [reverse the `case` logic and match `1` against the value of those arithmetic comparisons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239462).

Comment: +1, consider `if [ n < 0 ] - elif [ n <= 80 ] - elif [ n <= 100 ] ... - else`. Less typing, less error-prone.

Comment: @peterph It also takes longer to run.

Answer (score 6):

Actually this is really easy to do. The thing about `case` is that it will always expand only as much as is needed to find the first match against a pattern. That's spec'd behavior. And so you can just set it up with a known string and evaluate the patterns' expansions.

```
case  1:${number:--} in
(1:*[!0-9]*|1:0*[89]*)
  ! echo NAN
;;
($((number<81))*)
    echo "$number >=0<=80"
;;
($((number<101))*)
    echo "$number >=81<=100"
;;
($((number<121))*)
    echo "$number >=101<=120"
;;
($((number<301))*)
    echo "$number >=121<=300"
;;
esac
```

`case` will never expand any more of those patterns than it has to in order to find a leading 1 in the pattern. This is especially important when working with user input, because it means you can safely verify the contents of `$number` before ever trying to put it in an arithmetic expansion context in the same case statement in which you actually do put it in a math expansion.

Comment:  I like the way you think outside/around the box.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - i like `case`. theres some cool stuff you can do with `$((`math`))` and `case` - especially surrounding assignments in patterns that never happen until they need to - and you can even build parse trees that expand nested recursions if you populate the patterns with an `alias` chain. its the fastest way ive found to get a shell to do stuff like character translation and to swap characters for bytes values. it can be pretty fast - C-Locale ASCII+ <> octal very worst case is 7 basic POSIX pattern expansions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very nice but you can use this :

```
 #!/bin/ksh

read number  

case $number in
[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]|80) echo  echo ">=0<=80";;
8[1-9]|9[0-9]|100) echo ">=81<=100";;
10[1-9]|11[0-9]|120) echo ">=101<=120";;
12[1-9]|130) echo ">=121<=300";;
esac
```

Comment: You may want to "canonify" the number with $(($number)) to cover for numbers like "001" or "0x99"... That would also cover for " 12" and "12+12" which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: If you really want to be fussy than 001 is not a natural number it is a bad text representation of a natural number.
it is safe to replace 
sed "s/^0\+/0/; s/^[0]\([1-9]\)/\1/"